# Jquery toggle link not working on phone/tablet

Tags: jquery

I have a link that toggles visibility of a certain text element on a webpage. Example can be seen here: http://wasup.si/kin-pid48 (The plus icon near the text "Lastnosti izdelka"). It works fine on desktop, but doesn't function on a phone (android) or tablet (android). Didn't test on iPad yet, but still...it should work anywhere.

The link is written like this:

```
<a href="javascript: void(0);" style="display:block" onClick="toggleFeature()"><img id="togglePic" src="/images/plus.png" border="0"></a>
```

and toggleFeature is a function defined as such:

```
function toggleFeature() {
$('#features-container').toggle(400);
pic = $('#togglePic').attr('src');
if (pic.indexOf('plus') > 0) {
    $('#togglePic').attr('src','/images/minus.png');
} else {
    $('#togglePic').attr('src','/images/plus.png');
}
}
```

Any idea why this wouldn't work?

Comment: An onClick is for mouseclick, so it won't work on touch. Use jQuery's vclick:
`$("#idOfLink").on("vclick", function(){
        //stuff here
    });`

Comment: Even though google is one click away, it might be usefull to add this link to @user3153169 's comment.
http://api.jquerymobile.com/vclick/